# Using Cantor-Schroder-Bernstein Theorem to prove a statement (with my proposal)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, cardinals

My Question reads:

Use the Cantor–Schröder–Bernstein Theorem to prove the following.

The set of all integers whose digits are 6, 7, or 8 is denumerable

Now, my understanding of the definition of CSB Theorem is if cardinality of A less than or equal to cardinality B and cardinality B less than or equal to cardinality A, then cardinality A equals cardinality B.

I have started by setting S=the set of all integers whose digits are 6,7, or 8. From there I am not too sure what function to define. From this set S to what other set? And I know I would also have to show a function the other way around; in both cases one-to-one functions. I am more concerned as to how to go about setting this up. I am not too sure what is meant by integers whose digits are 6,7,or 8. Would this be a number like 67, or 86?

**Updated Answer**

I am working on defining f: Z->A by defining:

f(x)={6x, if x>0; 7x, if x=0; 8x, if x>0}

Can something like this be used to solve this direction?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, I know I have to show one to one in each direction. Then I need to define a function from A to the natural numbers? Not the integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re your last question: yes.

If $A$ is your set, then we have the inclusion $A\to\Bbb N$, $x\mapsto x$ showing $|A|\le |\Bbb N|$ and we have $\Bbb N\to X$, $n\mapsto 6\cdot \frac{10^n-1}{9}$ showing $|\Bbb N|\le |A|$.

Comment: Hmm, how do we know that A --> N is one to one? I understand it shows it in one direction. Also, why would it be a function to N, should it not be to Z (the integers) since this question deals with integers? Also, by X do you mean A instead?

Comment: Also, do this not just cover the case of 6 digit integers? This does not cover the 7 or 8.